# Транки в asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Есть 2 `asterisk` сервера, одинаково настроены, имеют одинаковые транки к провайдеру. Вопрос, если идёт внешний вызов, как провайдер решает по какому из 2х каналов пустить звонок? К 1 или 2 клиенту (астериску). Или всё же происходит проверка, допустим кто-то звонит на наш номер 89******. Звонок на этот номер автоматически посылается на номер секретаря (допустим 100). Но на первом сервере телефон зарегестрирован, а на втором нет. Провайдер посылает запрос нашим серверам и исходя из их ответа (dead/alive) он пускает дозвон к живому номеру/серверу. Всё так или я не прав?